# JS sort array by three types of sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting

I need to sort an array by the following order based on a search term.

1. Exact string.
2. Starts with.
3. Contains.

Code :

```js
var arr = ['Something here Hello', 'Hell', 'Hello'];

var term = 'Hello';

var sorted = arr.slice().sort((a, b) => {
  let value = 0;

  if (a.startsWith(term)) {
    value = -1;
  }

  if (a.indexOf(term) > -1) {
    value = -1;
  }

  if (a === term) {
    value = -1;
  }

  return value;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

The expected result is:

```
["Hello", "Hell", "Something here Hello"]
```

I'm not sure how to do this with the built-in sort function because it looks like it's not meant to use with cases like that. Any advice, please?

Comment: You have to *compare* `a` and `b`. Your current algorithm just returns `-1` or `0` for all your array elements.

Comment: `because it looks like it's not meant to use with cases like that` it looks like a bigger problem (and maybe the core of your problem) is that your sorting function is returning results that are [not logically equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison)! You should be returning `-1`, `0` but also `1`. Right now you only return one of two values - two objects are equal or smaller. It's functionally equivalent to returning a boolean as you still only have two outcomes.

Comment: @str it also returns `0` if the term is nowhere to be found. Not that it makes it better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a function which returns a value for the staged sorting.

Inside of the callback for sorting, you need to return the delta of the two values which reflects the relation between the two strings.

```js
const compareWith = term => string => {
        if (string === term) return 1;
        if (term.startsWith(string)) return 2; // switch string and term
        if (string.includes(term)) return 3;   // use includes
        return Infinity;                       // unknown strings move to the end
    };

var array = ['Something here Hello', 'Hell', 'Hello'],
    term = 'Hello',
    order = compareWith(term);

array.sort((a, b) => order(a) - order(b));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help.

Comment: This answer is godlike, I love it.